# Finding number of times days appear incrementally

Tags: php, date

I have an application that records user transactions into a database. The data recorded includes: the time a user performed a transaction (e.g. purchasing materials), the day (e.g. 2016-12-23), what the user transacted, etc. I have an admin panel that collects this data and shows the overall statistics. I need to analyse the data such that, for example;  if i need to find out all purchases made for that week (i.e.from Sunday to the current day of the week), i select all appearances from the database that have the dates from the immediate previous Sunday until the current day, so that i show a weekly statistics. 
Now, since the average is done weekly, i need only to get the current date, that of the previous sunday and the days in between. I know how to get these two but no idea how to get the middle dates depending on the day of the week.
Note that the time i huse is in the format

`$today = date("Y-m-d");`

and to get the previous sunday i use:

`$prevsunday = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("last Sunday"));`

I ask how to get the middle days, and how to handle the updated query.
Any suggestions to improve my query?

Comment: have you tried using: `+ x day` on the last sunday timestamp?

Comment: If the database engine you use supports it, you can use the SQL operator BETWEEN : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp. So current date and last sunday date are all you need to do what you want.

Comment: i have not tried that yet @Naruto .i'm trying it right now.

Comment: @Eria, i will try BETWEEN. the explanation at w3schools.com is awesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming MySQL, you can use `dayofweek` to figure out "previous sunday":

```
mysql> select curdate(), dayofweek(curdate()),
    curdate() - interval (dayofweek(curdate())-1) day AS sunday;
+------------+----------------------+------------+
| curdate()  | dayofweek(curdate()) | sunday     |
+------------+----------------------+------------+
| 2016-02-23 |                    3 | 2016-02-21 |
+------------+----------------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So you'd have something like

```
SELECT ...
...
WHERE dateofpurchase BETWEEN
    (curdate() - interval (dayofweek(curdate())-1) day)
   AND
     curdate();
```

Comment: i need the results to be the dates of those days in between with sunday and the current day inclusive.

Comment: which is what the `between` does. "get all purchases between last sunday and today"

Comment: seems my database doesn't support between since it isn't working and no errors